# How to apply a function on all columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame like the following:

```
a b c d e
1 2 3 1 1
2 3 0 1 1 
3 4 2 1 1
4 5 0 1 2
5 0 7 1 2
```

I would like to sum each column for each unique value in column `e`.
So my output should be:

```
a b c d e
6 9 5 3 1
9 5 7 2 2
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to summarise by group. You can do: `library(dplyr); data %>% (e) %>% summarise_all(sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `by`

```
cbind(do.call(rbind, by(d[-5], d$e, colSums)), e=unique(d$e))
#   a b c d e
# 1 6 9 5 3 1
# 2 9 5 7 2 2
```

or use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(. ~ e, d, FUN=sum)
#   e a b c d
# 1 1 6 9 5 3
# 2 2 9 5 7 2
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(a = 1:5, b = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L), c = c(3L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 7L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), e = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```